What's the significance of `SyntaxError: 'break' outside loop` v. `SyntaxError: 'continue' not properly in loop`?
I accept that, due to Python language limitation, continue must be within a loop "properly" i.e. "not nested in a function or class definition within that loop."
while True:
  def f():
    continue # SyntaxError: 'continue' not properly in loop
  f()

What's the significance of the difference at break, where the (arguably false) complaint is that it is "outside" loop?
while True:
  def f():
    break # SyntaxError: 'break' outside loop
  f() 

I see no relevant difference in the language reference.

break and continue are in a function, which may be called also outside loop or in a lot of interesting ways, so the break it is just in a different scope

It's not clear to me what you're asking.  They're both syntax errors for essentially the same reason.

You cannot have a break or a continue in a code block that is not a loop (for, while etc.). For example in both cases if you call function f, what would you expect to happen?

Is your question why these error messages differ in wording? The difference between "not properly inside" and "outside"?

Programming languages were also written by humans, who aren't always consistent nor flawless.

If you look at the functions responsible for compiling break and continue statements, you'll see the only difference has to do with break exiting the current loop. The wording of the error messages when no loop is involved isn't significant, just inconsistent.
static int
compiler_break(struct compiler *c, location loc)
{
    struct fblockinfo *loop = NULL;
    location origin_loc = loc;
    /* Emit instruction with line number */
    ADDOP(c, loc, NOP);
    RETURN_IF_ERROR(compiler_unwind_fblock_stack(c, &loc, 0, &loop));
    if (loop == NULL) {
        return compiler_error(c, origin_loc, "'break' outside loop");
    }
    RETURN_IF_ERROR(compiler_unwind_fblock(c, &loc, loop, 0));
    ADDOP_JUMP(c, loc, JUMP, loop->fb_exit);
    return SUCCESS;
}

static int
compiler_continue(struct compiler *c, location loc)
{
    struct fblockinfo *loop = NULL;
    location origin_loc = loc;
    /* Emit instruction with line number */
    ADDOP(c, loc, NOP);
    RETURN_IF_ERROR(compiler_unwind_fblock_stack(c, &loc, 0, &loop));
    if (loop == NULL) {
        return compiler_error(c, origin_loc, "'continue' not properly in loop");
    }
    ADDOP_JUMP(c, loc, JUMP, loop->fb_block);
    return SUCCESS;
}


PS Regardless, perhaps someone will correct breaks message to meet the standard of continue's ...  if the breakage to error message processors doesn't discourage.

This is simply invalid syntax, if you want to continue or break, it needs to be in the scope of a loop
while True:
    break  # refers to while

for index in rainge(100):
    if index > 10:
        break  # refers to for

When you start a new function as a closure, it's inheriting references from the outer scope, but not the loop context, so it's equivalent to this
def f():
    break  # SyntaxError

while True:
    f()

You can use return instead to leave the function scope
def f():
    return

while True:
    f()

or raise an Exception to leave the loop scope
def f():
    raise Exception()  # unhandled in `while` so loop is exited

while True:
    f()


"simply invalid syntax" Not simple enough to deliver consistent error messages, evidently :)

tbh I'm a bit surprised they have distinct messages too, not a more generic SyntaxError("unexpected outside loop context") - though really, it simply doesn't make sense in the language, like return outside a function - you could suggest a pull request to make the messages the same

OP isn't asking why it's a syntax error, only why the error messages are worded differently.

sort of - they're not a [python] dev by their style and profile, the errors would never be seen in real language use (as they are real SyntaxErrors, only a developer might briefly see them as they can't even be interpreted by the AST), and so implicitly curious about the language design

"it simply doesn't make sense in the language, like return outside a function" Well, the big difference is this break/continue is not outside the loop.
